# how can I slice the index of a data frame for dates

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Suppose I have the following data given

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> index = pd.date_range('20180101', periods=10, freq='D')
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10), index = index)
>>> df
                   0
2018-01-01 -1.420260
2018-01-02  0.797090
2018-01-03 -3.054759
2018-01-04  1.473528
2018-01-05 -1.061746
2018-01-06  0.352680
2018-01-07  0.030430
2018-01-08  0.682517
2018-01-09 -1.574081
2018-01-10 -2.828765
```

I would like to select the sub data frame which falls between two time stamps.
So for

```
>>> time1 = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-04')
>>> time2 = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-08')
```

I would like to select the rows somehow to get

```
2018-01-03 -3.054759
2018-01-04  1.473528
2018-01-05 -1.061746
2018-01-06  0.352680
2018-01-07  0.030430
2018-01-08  0.682517
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could

```
In [36]: df.loc['2018-01-03':'2018-01-08']
Out[36]:
                   0
2018-01-03 -0.301602
2018-01-04 -2.272758
2018-01-05 -0.227374
2018-01-06 -0.476740
2018-01-07  0.921640
2018-01-08 -2.025022
```

Or,

```
In [39]: df.loc[time1:time2]
Out[39]:
                   0
2018-01-04 -2.272758
2018-01-05 -0.227374
2018-01-06 -0.476740
2018-01-07  0.921640
2018-01-08 -2.025022
```

Or, use `truncate`

```
In [49]: df.truncate(before=time1, after=time2)
Out[49]:
                   0
2018-01-04 -2.272758
2018-01-05 -0.227374
2018-01-06 -0.476740
2018-01-07  0.921640
2018-01-08 -2.025022
```

Or, use

```
In [54]: df.loc[(df.index > '2018-01-03') & (df.index < '2018-01-08')]
Out[54]:
                   0
2018-01-04 -2.272758
2018-01-05 -0.227374
2018-01-06 -0.476740
2018-01-07  0.921640
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df.index.isin(pd.date_range(time1,time2))]
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. You should explain your answer so OP and others can learn to fix this problem in the future.